# Google Spreadsheet ArrayFormula where the value depends on the values above it

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm looking for a solution to an ArrayFormula problem where the value I put into column B depends on all of the values of column B above it.  (It's not a real circular reference, I can write the solution without an ArrayFormula).

Here's a simple version of what I'm trying to do.  Cells in column A contain positive or negative value.  If the value in A is positive, the same value will be copied to B.  However, if A is negative, the value of A copied to be will be the minimum of either A or the cumulative sum of B for all the cells above it.

```
A     B
  1     1
  2     2
 -2    -2
  3     3
-10    -4
```

This the formula in B2 that I manually copied down, that does this:

```
=if(A2>0,A2,max(-sum(B$1:B1),A2))
```

you could view A as a request to either put money in an account (+) or take money out of an account (-) and B is the response to what happens, it either all goes in, or you can pull the max out.

I'm happy to have additional columns to do intermediate calculations if necessary, but I just can't seem to figure out a way to get around the pseudocircular reference where the value to put in Bn depends on Bn-1.

Ideally I'd love to have it set up so that my ranges in the ArrayFormula would be of the form B2:B so that I don't have to worry about ever extending them when the data grows.

Comment: "if A is negative, the value of A copied to be will be the minimum of either A or the cumulative sum of B for all the cells above it"... do you mean maximum?

Comment: It's the biggest negative number I can subtract.  It's hard to say in English, is that min, max, farthest from zero?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your thinking behind how you benefit from using an Array Formula.. Array formula is generally used where you want one value from similar operation performed on several elements of more than one arrays. You will need to enter a formula in every cell in column B, so how do you think array formula will help you? It could be just me, that I don't understand it.

Comment: What I like about the array formula is that I can automate a bunch of my sheets easily.  I don't have to copy down formulae when I add  new data.  For many of my sheets, I have a worksheet set as the "input sheet" where data is added.  Then I have a bunch of hidden "calculation" sheets full of array formulae, and then a result sheet at the end.  This is just one of the computations that I haven't figured out how to array-ify so that I can hide it over in my calculation sheets.

Comment: Ah OK I understand what you mean. However, what would happen on the next line? Does the "outstanding" request of -6 need to be fulfilled, or is it ignored thereafter?

Comment: This is a super simplified example.  I have another column that handles the -6 for something else later.  For the example here, you can just ignore the -6 afterwards.  The non-array formula that I put in the original question does exactly what I want it to do, I just want to array-ify it.

Comment: In that case, I don't believe these sort of "self-referencing" problems - where the array formula is to reference its output on previous rows - can  be achieved with an array formula. I would be happy to be proven wrong though. That being said, it would be trivial to write a custom formula in Goolge Apps Script to do the same.

Comment: I agree with AdamL. Miked, would a custom formula be acceptable to you ?

Comment: Yes, I could live with a custom formula, as long as I can get some type of auto-fill when new data is added to column A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code should provide you with a custom function that kinda behaves like an arrayformula. You can reference a whole column with it. [Click here for an example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E8fWiTJcxhX32ObxPdtlxlAkzPt8o-e6gPX4a3u7GlE/edit?usp=sharing) (Cell C2 holds the custom formula).

The code used is this:

```
function CF(range) {
var out = [];
range.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
})
    .filter(function (d) {
        return d !== '';
    })
    .forEach(function (x) {
        out.push(x > 0 ? x : Math.max(x, -out.reduce(function (p, c) {
            return p + c;
        })))
    });
return out;
}
```

I hope this helps ?

Comment: That's super cool!  I'll have to sit down and go through that to learn what it does.  My first reading of this is that the .reduce creates a long list of all of the cells we are going to use (e.g fills in the A2:A), the .filter removes any cells that are empty, and the .forEach actually fills in the value for each cell.  Then it returns an array which google knows to just fill down the range?  That's really clever! Thanks!

Comment: I sat down to play with this this weekend, and I have a question.  I'm new to javascript, so if this is obvious to you, I'm sorry.  Why the concatenation and filter?  Why not just have the .forEach.  I just did that and I get the same answer and it's faster because I'm not looping through the range so many times.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, The concat part is actually to turn the 2D-array (from range) into a 1D array. The filter part is indeed optional. Wen writing code it is difficult to know how someone is going to use the code. If you want to use open ended ranges in the formula (e.g. "A1:A") while you don't have data in all the cells you would want to filter out the empty cells. Else you will have a lot of zeroes in the output column. If you only reference ranges as far as they have data (e.g.' "A1:A13") then you don't need the filter part. Hope that makes sense ? In the example sheet I took both out. Check the outcome.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I only needed a 1D array, never thought of the 2D case.  Thanks for your code, I never thought of writing functions for google sheets, and now I'm having tons of fun.

Comment: @JPV Forgive me, but in an attempt to make a copy of your sheet, so that I could experiment, I clicked "Add to My Drive". It turns out that this doesn't work as expected but "Moves" it to my drive instead of making a copy (after that, the link I clicked changed from "Add to My Drive" to "Move to..."! Sorry, but please can you move it back again as I can see know way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSnow, the file in my StackOverflow folder on my drive.